# How to find duplicates of particular column in data table in C# and return the duplicate's row number as output

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, duplicates

I Have a Datatable as below below image and i need to find the duplicates of only three columns(startdate,stopdate,Name), If duplicates found i need the output as row number of corresponding duplicate rows ( In this case, output should be 2,4,5) Row 2 and 4 are duplicates of Row 1 and Row 5 is the duplicate of Row 3)

```
+------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| S.no | StartDate | StopDate  | Name | Test1 | Test2 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-------+
|    1 | 16-Dec-19 | 17-Dec-19 | Abc  |     1 |     2 |
|    2 | 16-Dec-19 | 17-Dec-19 | Abc  |     2 |     2 |
|    3 | 16-Dec-19 | 17-Dec-19 | def  |     3 |     2 |
|    4 | 16-Dec-19 | 17-Dec-19 | Abc  |     4 |     2 |
|    5 | 16-Dec-19 | 17-Dec-19 | def  |     5 |     2 |
+------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-------+
```

I am new to Linq Concept, If this scenario is possible in Linq, Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Please, do not post code and data as images

Comment: Datatable Rows donot support LINQ . you may have to write logic to compare the element with all the other rows

Comment: Hi Pavel, Thanks for the response, I tried to replicate the data table here in words but i cant able to replicate it so for clarity of the issue i just post a picture of dummy data.

Comment: You can post this data as code and others can help you. Do you have this data in a list or it's a `DataTable`? Data types of columns will be helpful also

Comment: You can use groupby : dt.AsEnumberable().GroupBy(x => new {x.Field<DataTime>("StartDate").ToString(), x.Field<DateTime>("EndDate").ToString(), x.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```cs
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Sno",typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("StartDate ", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("StopDate", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

var dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = 1;
dr[1] = new DateTime(2019,12,16);
dr[2] = new DateTime(2019, 12, 17);
dr[3] = "ABC";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = 2;
dr[1] = new DateTime(2019, 12, 16);
dr[2] = new DateTime(2019, 12, 17);
dr[3] = "ABC";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = 3;
dr[1] = new DateTime(2019, 12, 16);
dr[2] = new DateTime(2019, 12, 18);
dr[3] = "ABC";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

var dupes = dt.AsEnumerable().
    Select(x => new { StartDate = (DateTime) x[1], EndDate = (DateTime)x[2], Name = (string) x[3], Sno = (int) x[0] }).
    Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable().
    Where(y => ((int) y[0] <  x.Sno) && (DateTime)y[1] == x.StartDate && (DateTime)y[2] == x.EndDate && (string) y[3] == x.Name).Any()).
    Select(x => x.Sno).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much...It Works

Answer (score 0):

Try this linq.

```
data
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.startdate, x.stopdate, x.name })
    .Select(x => x.Skip(1).ToList())
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```